# ros publish pcl::ModelCoefficients

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following "How to use a pcl tutorial on ROS" under /pcl/Tutorials. I managed to build and run section 4.1 with no problems but when I build 4.2 I get the following error:

[ 50%] [100%] Built target example2
Building CXX object my_pcl_tutorial/CMakeFiles/example.dir/src/example.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/serialization.h:37:0,
from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/publisher.h:34,
from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/ros.h:45,
from /home/ndivhuwo/Documents/cloud/src/my_pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum::value(const M&) [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h:255:104:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::md5sum(const M&) [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’
/home/ndivhuwo/Documents/cloud/src/my_pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp:49:28:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h:126:34: error: ‘const struct pcl::ModelCoefficients’ has no member named ‘__getMD5Sum’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::DataType::value(const M&) [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h:264:106:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::datatype(const M&) [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’
/home/ndivhuwo/Documents/cloud/src/my_pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp:49:28:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h:143:36: error: ‘const struct pcl::ModelCoefficients’ has no member named ‘__getDataType’
In file included from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/publisher.h:34:0,
from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/ros.h:45,
from /home/ndivhuwo/Documents/cloud/src/my_pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static uint32_t ros::serialization::Serializer::serializedLength(typename boost::call_traits::param_type) [with T = pcl::ModelCoefficients, uint32_t = unsigned int, typename boost::call_traits::param_type = const pcl::ModelCoefficients&]’:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/serialization.h:170:43:   instantiated from ‘uint32_t ros::serialization::serializationLength(const T&) [with T = pcl::ModelCoefficients, uint32_t = unsigned int]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/serialization.h:846:45:   instantiated from ‘ros::SerializedMessage ros::serialization::serializeMessage(const M&) [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/publisher.h:118:7:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’
/home/ndivhuwo/Documents/cloud/src/my_pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp:49:28:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/serialization.h:142:34: error: ‘const struct pcl::ModelCoefficients’ has no member named ‘serializationLength’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::serialization::Serializer::write(Stream&, typename boost::call_traits::param_type) [with Stream = ros::serialization::OStream, T = pcl::ModelCoefficients, typename boost::call_traits::param_type = const pcl::ModelCoefficients&]’:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/serialization.h:152:3:   instantiated from ‘void ros::serialization::serialize(Stream&, const T&) [with T = pcl::ModelCoefficients, Stream = ros::serialization::OStream]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/serialization.h:853:3:   instantiated from ‘ros::SerializedMessage ros::serialization::serializeMessage(const M&) [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/publisher.h:118:7:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’
/home/ndivhuwo/Documents/cloud/src/my_pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp:49:28:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/serialization.h:125:5: error: ‘const struct pcl::ModelCoefficients’ has no member named ‘serialize’
In file included from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/serialization.h:37:0,
from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/publisher.h:34,
from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/ros.h:45,
from /home/ndivhuwo/Documents/cloud/src/my_pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum::value() [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h:228:103:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::md5sum() [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/advertise_options.h:92:5:   instantiated from ‘void ros::AdvertiseOptions::init(const string&, uint32_t, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const SubscriberStatusCallback&) [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients, std::string = std::basic_string, uint32_t = unsigned int, ros::SubscriberStatusCallback = boost::function<void(const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher&)>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:239:7:   instantiated from ‘ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const string&, uint32_t, bool) [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients, std::string = std::basic_string, uint32_t = unsigned int]’
/home/ndivhuwo/Documents/cloud/src/my_pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp:69:58:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h:121:37: error: ‘__s_getMD5Sum’ is not a member of ‘pcl::ModelCoefficients’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::DataType::value() [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h:237:105:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::datatype() [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/advertise_options.h:93:5:   instantiated from ‘void ros::AdvertiseOptions::init(const string&, uint32_t, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const SubscriberStatusCallback&) [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients, std::string = std::basic_string, uint32_t = unsigned int, ros::SubscriberStatusCallback = boost::function<void(const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher&)>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:239:7:   instantiated from ‘ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const string&, uint32_t, bool) [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients, std::string = std::basic_string, uint32_t = unsigned int]’
/home/ndivhuwo/Documents/cloud/src/my_pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp:69:58:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h:138:39: error: ‘__s_getDataType’ is not a member of ‘pcl::ModelCoefficients’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::Definition::value() [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h:246:107:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::definition() [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/advertise_options.h:94:5:   instantiated from ‘void ros::AdvertiseOptions::init(const string&, uint32_t, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const SubscriberStatusCallback&) [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients, std::string = std::basic_string, uint32_t = unsigned int, ros::SubscriberStatusCallback = boost::function<void(const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher&)>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:239:7:   instantiated from ‘ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const string&, uint32_t, bool) [with M = pcl::ModelCoefficients, std::string = std::basic_string, uint32_t = unsigned int]’
/home/ndivhuwo/Documents/cloud/src/my_pcl_tutorial/src/example.cpp:69:58:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_traits.h:155:48: error: ‘__s_getMessageDefinition’ is not a member of ‘pcl::ModelCoefficients’
make[2]: *** [my_pcl_tutorial/CMakeFiles/example.dir/src/example.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [my_pcl_tutorial/CMakeFiles/example.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed

The line I think it's complaining about in the beginning looks like this:

// Publish the model coefficients

pub.publish (coefficients); where coefficients is
pcl::ModelCoefficients coefficients;

I ran this code following documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation under the pcl website and it worked and I didn't have to publish anything to a topic here but just printed to screen, this is why I think the problem is trying to publish a pcl::ModelCoefficients type or maybe I am just missing something. Any help will be appreciated. I am running ros hyrdo with pcl17 installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93306/ros-publish-pcl::modelcoefficients/) by [HiroCollins](https://answers.ros.org/users/6334/hirocollins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-10-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, PCL is not integrated in ROS anymore. But there is package that allows you to perform conversions between ros and pcl messages. In order to publish pcl::ModelCoefficients you must do the following:

#include < pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>

...

ros::Publisher pub;

// Create a ROS publisher for the output point cloud

pub = nh.advertise< pcl_msgs::ModelCoefficients> ("output", 1);

// ros message

pcl_msgs::ModelCoefficients ros_coefficients;

// pcl message

pcl::ModelCoefficients pcl_coefficients;

....

pcl_conversions::fromPCL(pcl_coefficients, ros_coefficients);

pub.publish(ros_coefficients);

---

Originally posted by [sergifoix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1935/sergifoix/) with karma: 36 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-07-23**:
Thanks for answering this question but not bothering to update the wiki, to ensure that people continue to have the most horrible experience trying to learn ROS.

**Comment by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on 2015-06-04**:
Another tutorial follower here. Now that I've made the changes, how do I get rviz to display the result?

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2015-06-04**:
Try [this example](https://gist.github.com/ntraft/c9e74e31cebb25b9be4c). If you only want to see the planes/non-planes there is a way to copy just those points into a new point cloud but I forget how. Some other PCL tutorial might show it.